# how to extract some rows in a data file by comparing with another data file? (merging)

Tags: shell, shell-script, sed, awk, perl

I have 2 different file :

```
first file:
id1 19501112
id2 19831207
1d4 20001212
id6 20000101
id10 20061213
id11 20081212
id12 20100109
id13 20101218
id14 20101212
id15 20111111
id16 20150919
id20 20141415
```

and second file:

```
id100
id2
id4
id44
id10
id16
id2000
id34
id5
id7
```

so I want to extract those rows in file 1 which ids are in common with ids in second file. so I want my output file looks like:

```
id2 19831207
1d4 20001212
id10 20061213
id16 20150919
```

any suggestion please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using GNU grep:

```
grep -w -f file2.txt file1.txt
```

This tells `grep` to match on only whole "words", and to get the list of patterns to search for from file2.txt

If there's any chance that the contents of file2.txt may appear in the remainder of lines in file1.txt, then you can use sed and bash's process substitution like so:

```
grep -f <(sed -e 's/^/^/ ; s/$/\\b/' file2.txt) file1.txt
```

This uses sed to transform each `idN` line into `^idN\b` before using it in `grep -f`.

Comment: btw, is `1d4` in file1 supposed to be `id4` - i presume it is, otherwise it won't match `id4` from file2.

Comment: well, that fixes it for OP's particular example; there's a reason why most people would use tools that operate on fields (based on an unambiguous delimiter): as soon as the ids in file1.txt change to something like `20.1` or `10-1` that "word \boundary"  will screw things up...

Comment: of course it fixes it for the OP's particular example - that's how questions and answers work.  and just like any answer, it can and should be adapted to suit variant questions.  e.g. for your variant: `grep -F -f <(sed -e 's/$/ /' file2.txt) file1.txt`